# About Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, unified-theories

Did Feyman suggest even though Q.M. has great predictive power no one will ever really understand it ? Some people have said there may be hidden variables that explain underlying principles of Q.M. but has this been ruled out? Has Q.M. been put in an axiomatic framework?

Comment: Yes, quantum mechanics has been put in an axiomatic framework. Local hidden variable theories have been ruled out experimentally. If Feynman did say such a thing he meant that QM is difficult to understand intuitively.

Comment: Great information..The axiomatic framework , does it involve non-commutative matrices?

Comment: Check out this wikipedia page 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_formulation_of_quantum_mechanics#Mathematical_structure_of_quantum_mechanics

non-commutative matrices are not explicitly mentioned but they fit in as operators on the Hilbert space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, local hidden variables have not been ruled out experimentally so far. Not without the so called loopholes. For what it's worth, Zeilinger called those loopholes "essential" (arXiv:quant-ph/9810080v1 (Phys.Rev.Lett. 81 (1998) 5039-5043)).

Comment: as far as I know all the serious hidden variable theories for quantum mechanics either violate special relativity or are just a more complicated mathematically way of doing the same calculations. For example the pilot wave Bohm theory can only work in first quantization levels, not in second quantization. And special relativity has been proven with a lot of measurements so to say there is no experimental evidence so far is stretching the truth. Hidden variables cannot accommodate SR.

Comment: @anna v: May I note that my wording "have not been ruled out experimentally so far" seems at least somewhat different from yours "there is no experimental evidence". I stand by my wording.

Comment: Well, in my book, they have been ruled  out experimentally by the great multiplicity of experiments that validate special relativity. One cannot have a fundamental theory violating special relativity.

Comment: @anna v: Well, "in my book" is about an opinion, not about a fact. On the other hand, the race to close the loopholes experimentally is feverish, the relevant articles are published in the best journals, so maybe this issue is not so clear-cut. My take is influenced by the results of my work, e.g., http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/480/art%253A10.1140%252Fepjc%252Fs10052-013-2371-4.pdf?auth66=1406861526_5b69b9c60ee74942a8a6911df91832f5&ext=.pdf (published in Eur. Phys. J. C): spinor electrodynamics is local and Lorentz-invariant, but can be embedded into a quantum field theory.

Answer (score 2):

Feynman [said](http://bouman.chem.georgetown.edu/general/feynman.html) the following about QM:

> The difficulty really is psychological and exists in the perpetual torment that results from your saying to yourself, "But how can it be like that?" which is a reflection of uncontrolled but utterly vain desire to see it in terms of something familiar. I will not describe it in terms of an analogy with something familiar; I will simply describe it. There was a time when the newspapers said that only twelve men understood the theory of relativity. I do not believe there ever was such a time. There might have been a time when only one man did, because he was the only guy who caught on, before he wrote his paper. But after people read the paper a lot of people understood the theory of relativity in some way or other, certainly more than twelve. On the other hand, I think I can safely say that nobody understands quantum mechanics. So do not take the lecture too seriously, feeling that you really have to understand in terms of some model what I am going to describe, but just relax and enjoy it. I am going to tell you what nature behaves like. If you will simply admit that maybe she does behave like this, you will find her a delightful, entrancing thing. Do not keep saying to yourself, if you can possible avoid it, "But how can it be like that?" because you will get 'down the drain', into a blind alley from which nobody has escaped. Nobody knows how it can be like that.

This statement doesn't make sense. What exactly is it that Feynman thinks we can't understand? Feynman leaves this unclear and there is a reason why it is unclear. It's not possible to give an exact explanation of why you can't understand something, as opposed to why you happen not to understand it at the moment. Any such explanation would explain the thing that you allegedly can't understand and then say why you can't understand it, which is a contradiction. You can say that you don't understand something at the moment and then explain the problems, but that is different from saying you can't understand something.

I don't see any particular reason to think we can't understand quantum mechanics more deeply than we do now. I think there is a lot of material that helps us understand quantum mechanics more deeply than Feynman did in some respects, see

http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.5082

http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3245

http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033

http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007

http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223.

You ask whether QM has been put in an axiomatic framework. The value of such a framework is to help solve some problem with a theory. You pick some set of assumptions and explain their consequences and thereby explain the consequences of the theory and how it explains some experimental result, say. Different people have proposed different sets of axioms to help elaborate different aspects of the theory, see for example the papers by Zurek or Deutsch linked above.

You ask about hidden variables. Hidden variables can't underlie QM because they contradict QM. In QM physical systems are described by evolving sets of Hermitian operators. At any given time, some of those observables do not have a sharp value Hidden variables theories describes physical systems in terms of evolving sets of scalars all of which have sharp values. Most talk about hidden variables does not propose any specific hidden variable theory and so in most cases there is nothing to test. There are some instances where there might be something to test, like some versions of the pilot wave theory. I don't see much reason to test them since it is unclear what problem they solve that can't be solved by taking QM seriously as a description of the world and working out the consequences. They do tend to raise very serious difficulties, such as being incompatible with relativity. In addition when the pilot wave theory explains something the corpuscles play no role in the explanation and without them the theory is just the same as QM without the dubious assumption of collapse:

http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0403094.

Comment: Is the main point of Q.M. is that it is a very accurate theory for predicting subatomic phenomena? Yet as a descriptive theory of nature it is not 'intuitive' (it is counter-intuitive). What does Quantum Theory 'think' of String Theory?

Comment: QM is no just about subatomic phenomena. A correct understanding of EPR experiments requires applying QM to macroscopic objects, see the 9906007 and 1109.6223 references above. Intuition is just stuff that people currently think is obvious so QM being counter-intuitive is not a criticism.
String theory is an attempt to invent a quantum theory of gravity. I am not aware of any reason why they should be incompatible.